# Append user data to url before sending request in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

What would be the easiest way to append form data to a json url prior to sending the request? I know next to nothing about php but Im trying either way

The PHP I have so far, I need to replace the ZIP before.json with the content im getting from $_GET['zip']

```
<?php
  $zip = $_GET['zip'];
  $zip_data = file_get_contents($zip);
  $weather_data = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/myapi/conditions/q/ZIP.json");
  echo $weather_data;
?>
```

Comment: No information about the Javascript you have written, or what this PHP script has to do with it.

Comment: The javascript isnt important to the question, I am just asking how to replace part of a string with content in PHP

Comment: ok.  The solutions below will work for you then :) .  The whole "JavaScript" details in your original edit really threw me off.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I removed that since I was going to ask a slightly different question originally but forgot to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP if you just put the variable name inside a string that is quoted with double quotes, it puts the value into the string:

```
$weather_data = file_get_contents(".../q/$zip.json");
```

You can also put curly brackets around it to make it cleaner to read:

```
$weather_data = file_get_contents(".../q/{$zip}.json");
```

Or you can close the string, use the dot operator to concatenate, and reopen the string:

```
$weather_data = file_get_contents(".../q/" . $zip . ".json");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
"http://api.wunderground.com/api/myapi/conditions/q/ZIP.json"
```

With

```
sprintf("http://api.wunderground.com/api/myapi/conditions/q/%s.json", $_GET['zip'])
```

(or whatever variable you want to take it's place)
[More on string formatting with sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf)